# Auto set field in Django Model, depending on another user submitted field

Tags: python, django

Say I have this code:

```
from django.db import models

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

then I'm able to create a 'Place':

```
>>> p1 = Restaurant(name='Demon Dogs', address='944 W. Fullerton')
>>> p1.save()
```

Here's the point. I'd like to have a preset dictionary like:

```
autoadress = {'Demon Dogs':'944 W. Fullerton', 'Eat attack':'100 Green Meadows', 'Pizza Fast':'50 E. High Hill'}
```

so that when a user creates a 'Restaurant' by only specifying it's name:

```
>>> p1 = Restaurant(name='Demon Dogs')
>>> p1.save()
```

A new Restaurant with name='Demon Dogs' and address='944 W. Fullerton' was created

How should I do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AUTOADDRESS = {'Demon Dogs':'944 W. Fullerton', 'Eat attack':'100 Green Meadows', 'Pizza Fast':'50 E. High Hill'}

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def clean(self):
        if not self.address:
            self.address = AUTOADDRESS.get(self.name, '')
```